# How to group by columns and store information in lists to avoid losing it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, matching

I try to set up a matching table but my base data holds some errors. I have a picture in my head what the result looks like but till now I did not find out how to receive it. Maybe someone of you can help me.

Basically I have a table that is based on different small matching tables and I want to set up a matching table that combines all that information. It might happen that we get error circles.

Basedata:

```
df

>       t1  t2  t3
> 0     a   c   NaN
> 1     b   d   NaN
> 0     NaN c   f
> 1     NaN c   g
> 0     h   NaN f
> 1     b   NaN j
```

I planned to merge the table column by column what means that I start with `t1` and 'merge' the elements (in this case b), what results in

```
df_processed = df.groupby(['t1']).first().reset_index()
frames = [df_processed, df[df['t1'].isnull()]]
df = pd.concat(frames)
df
>       t1  t2  t3
> 0     a   c   NaN
> 1     b   d   j
> 2     NaN c   f
> 0     NaN c   g
> 1     h   NaN f
```

When there are no problems within the column there is no problem but if there are problems it does not work any more.

When I want to continue with `t2` there is a merging problem because there are two possible values for 'c' in col `t3`. I want to get all columns as lists and store the information in the lists like this (result after processing col `t1` and `t2`):

```
df
>       t1      t2      t3
> 0     [a]     [c]     [f, g]
> 1     [b]     [d]     [j]
> 1     [h]     [NaN]   [f]
```

final table after processing all columns:

```
df
>       t1      t2      t3
> 0     [a, h]  [c]     [f, g]
> 1     [b]     [d]     [j]
```

I hope I made clear what I am looking for. In case you have any questions feel free to aks :-)

Best

P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `groupby` and then `apply` a `list`:

```
df_new = df.groupby('index')['t1'].apply(list)
```

In the above I am referring to 'index' as your un-labelled column on 0 and 1 in your example data frame.

Comment: Hello GhandiFloss, thanks for your answer. I do not see how I can use your idea to find the solution I am looking for. Maybe I simply do not get it but why du you want to use the index? I would say that it is more or less random after my initial table generation. I should have left it out of my min example.

Comment: That is just the column of reference. So for your example with 't2' and 't3' it would be: `t2_grouped = df.groupby('t2')['t3'].apply(list)`